# mysql: Java api to call mysql metadata service

Tags: mysql

Is there any java api to call mysql metadata service? The things I am particularly interested in is getting schema of the table using api not modifying the schema of the table.

Answer (score 0):

The best source for getting table metadata is MySQL itself. Use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables/views in MySQL to get this data. You can execute the queries and read the results set back like a normal query.

For table information:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

For columns:

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

You can use this form for indexes on InnoDB:

```
SELECT t.name AS `Table`,
   i.name AS `Index`,
   GROUP_CONCAT(f.name ORDER BY f.pos) AS `Columns`
 FROM information_schema.innodb_sys_tables t 
 JOIN information_schema.innodb_sys_indexes i USING (table_id) 
 JOIN information_schema.innodb_sys_fields f USING (index_id)
 WHERE t.schema = 'sakila'
 GROUP BY 1,2;
```